# Plotting and Sampling From Decision Boundary in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras

I have a simple classification network that takes in a vector of length 2 and makes a whole number prediction. I am trying to better understand the decision boundary of the prediction. I have a data set of 10,000 points, with a training set of size 9,000. The features are vectors of length 2 in the box [-1,1]^2 and the labels are one-hot encoded vectors of length 3. From [link](https://jonchar.net/notebooks/Artificial-Neural-Network-with-Keras/), I have gotten a way to plot the decision boundary with code as follows:

```py
def plot_decision_boundary(X, y, model, steps=1000, cmap='Paired'):
    """
    Function to plot the decision boundary and data points of a model.
    Data points are colored based on their actual label.
    """
    cmap = plt.get_cmap(cmap)
    
    # Define region of interest by data limits
    xmin, xmax = X[:,0].min() - 1, X[:,0].max() + 1
    ymin, ymax = X[:,1].min() - 1, X[:,1].max() + 1
    steps = 1000
    x_span = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, steps)
    y_span = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, steps)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x_span, y_span)

    # Make predictions across region of interest
    labels = model.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

    # Plot decision boundary in region of interest
    z = labels.reshape(xx.shape)
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.contourf(xx, yy, z, cmap=cmap, alpha=0.5)

    # Get predicted labels on training data and plot
    train_labels = model.predict(X)
    ax.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=y, cmap=cmap, lw=0)
    return(fig,ax)
```

where in turn I call
`plot_decision_boundary(train_features, train_labels_onehot, model, cmap='RdBu')` to create the plot of the decision boundary (see example in the link above). Unfortunately, I get the error

[image: Figure of Error]

Comment: It looks like it's an issue with how your X is being accessed.  What type is that X and what shape does it have?

Comment: X is a pandas dataframe of 9000 rows x 2 columns and y is a numpy array with 9000 elements, each a vector of length 3.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that since X is a pandas DataFrame it cannot be accessed by slice the way you are doing it.

I.e. `X[:,0]` will not give you the 0'th column of a data frame X.

Instead, you have two options.  Either, use `iloc` and make the slice like you attempted there:

`X.iloc[:,0]` to get the 0'th column.

Or, if you know the column's name you could just say `X["column_name"]`.  You can find out what the column names are with `X.columns`.

Comment: I did that and this is the error I got:


ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [95], line 1
----> 1 plot_decision_boundary(train_features, train_labels_onehot, model, cmap='RdBu')

Cell In [94], line 20, in plot_decision_boundary(X, y, model, steps, cmap)
     17 labels = model.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
     19 # Plot decision boundary in region of interest
---> 20 z = labels.reshape(xx.shape)
     22 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
     23 ax.contourf(xx, yy, z, cmap=cmap, alpha=0.5)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3000000 into shape (1000,1000)